# How to convert string into JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json, string

I have a string with value `abc@xyz.com.`
I have to pass this value to server like:

```
{"email":"abc@xyz.com"}
```

I am passing value to server like this using `okhttp`:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("email", email);
new PostMethodWithProgress(login_url, map, this, new Callback()
{
    @Override
    public void done(String reply)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(reply);

            if (object.getString("status").equals("200"))
            {

                //Toast Success Message
            }
            else
            {
                //Toast Failure Message
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("ASA", "Error is: " + e);
        }
    }
}).execute();
```

How do i do it?

Comment: Whats the problem with above code??Did you get any error??

Comment: Json Format Error, coz I am directly passing abc@xyz.com, I have to pass it like {"email":"abc@xyz.com"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `JSONObject` to achieve this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("email", "abc@xyz.com");

String result = jsonObject.toString();
```

**Output:**

```
{"email":"abc@xyz.com"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Gson  convert string to model and model to string easily
`ConvertModel convertModel = new Gson().fromJson(reply, ConvertModel .class);`

Then you can validate easily

Comment: what is ConvertModel ?

Comment: take the string then make the model class whatever values is there then use   ConvertModel  instance of your class

like that below inside your Model Class and generate setter and getter

    @SerializedName("Id")
    private String id = "";

    @SerializedName("FirstName")
    private String firstName = "";

Answer (score 1):

easy way use this code to pass jsonobject as string in okhttp

```
String jsonString = "";
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("email", "abc@xyz.com");
            obj.put("pwd", "12356");

            jsonString = obj.toString();
            //out put like this -> {"email":"abc@xyz.com","pwd":"123456"}
            Log.d("JsonString__",jsonString);
        }catch (Exception e){};
```

Answer (score 0):

`JsonObject` is a modifiable set of name/value mappings. Names are unique, non-null strings. Values may be any mix of `JSONObject`, `JSONArray`, `Strings`, `Booleans`, `Integers`, `Longs`, `Doubles` or `NULL`.

for your case `key` is **email** and `value` is **abc@xyz.com** so as I told `JsonObject` we can put both key and value pair like below -

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
object.put("email","abc@xyz.com");
```

If we convert above `JsonObject` to string then its value would be -

```
{"email":"abc@xyz.com"}
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try out this code with your data.

```
/**
 * This method is used to create text size and color code json and store it in json object.
 *
 * @param textSize       text size entered into edit text.
 * @param colorOfPreview text color of custom text color.
 * @return return json object of created text size and color.
 */
private String createJSONObject(String textSize, int colorOfPreview) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        // put your values here 
        jsonObject.put("textSize", textSize);
        jsonObject.put("textColor", colorOfPreview);
        return jsonObject.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```